# Question regarding translating English into first-order logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, logic-translation

Someone asked this question: "A language $L$ that is regular will have
the following property: there will be some number $N$ (that depends on $L$) such that if $s$ is a string in $L$ (a $string$ is a sequence of characters) whose length is at least $N$ then $s$ can be written as $xyz$ where $y$ is not the empty string and $xy^iz$ is in the language $L$ for every nonnegative integer $i$."

[Translating English into First Order Logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528213/translating-english-into-first-order-logic)

My question how would one even translate that into first order logic? The user started writing out his attempted approach. But I couldn't quite follow it so I was wondering how one could even write such statements in first order logic. I looked into pumping lemma as one of the comments suggested but it didn't help me much. It got me slightly more confused.

P.S. I'm sorry if I broke any rules in stating this question. I'm new to the site.

Answer (score 1):

Why do we *ever* bother to translate bits of mathematical English into the symbolism of first-order logic?

Primarily because the quantifier-variable plus connectives representation of statements is wonderfully clear and non-ambiguous about logical structure. Careless or sloppy vernacular talk may fail to distinguish between the propositions represented by $P \lor (Q \land R)$ and $(P \lor Q) \land R$ [Recall the ambiguous invitation: "Bring your partner or come alone and have a good time!"]. Logical notation forces us to distinguish, as it also forces us to distinguish $\forall x \neg Px$ and $\neg\forall xPx$ [compare the ambiguous "Everyone has not yet arrived"], and to distinguish $\forall x\exists yRxy$ and $\exists y\forall xRxy$, and so on and so forth.

So the key thing in rendering statements of mathematical English into the notation of first-order logic is to do enough to make logical structure perspicuous (in particular do enough to reveal the *scope* of various logical operators, i.e. to reveal just which bits of the proposition they govern). In this case, the statement after the colon has something like this sort of logical shape

$$\exists n\forall s[l(s)\geq n \to \exists x\exists y\exists z(s =  x^{\cap}y^{\cap}z \land y \neq 0 \land \forall i\,x^{\cap}y^i{}^{\cap}z \in L )]$$

if we take the quantifiers to be implicitly appropriately sorted so $s, x, y, z$ run over $L$-strings, and $n$ and $i$ over non-negative numbers (and where ${}^{\cap}$ is concatenation). The further finer details (e.g. whether you choose to *explicitly* type the variables by writing e.g. $\forall x \in L$ where $L$ is the set of $L$-strings) won't matter -- in most contexts -- so much as revealing the overall quantificational structure and scope dependencies.

I hope this helps ...